# Error with ntwitter module for node.js

Tags: node.js, express, twitter

I'm trying to build a Twitter streaming app using node.js and the ntwitter module, here's my code :

```
var app = require('express').createServer(),
twitter=require('ntwitter');

app.listen(3000);

var feed = new twitter({
consumer_key: 'MY KEY',
consumer_secret:'MY SECRET KEY',
access_tocken_key:'MY ACCESS TOCKEN KEY',
access_tocken_secret:'MY ACCESS TOCKEN SECRET'
});

feed.stream('statuses/filter',{track: ['love', 'hate']}, function(stream){
stream.on('data',function(tweet){
    console.log(tweet.text);
});
});
```

But here's what I get :

```
events.js:74
    throw TypeError('Uncaught, unspecified "error" event.');
          ^
TypeError: Uncaught, unspecified "error" event.
at TypeError (<anonymous>)
at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:74:15)
at ClientRequest.<anonymous> (/Users/maximeheckel/Documents/My_Repositories/nodetwitter/node_modules/ntwitter/lib/twitter.js:251:14)
at ClientRequest.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:95:17)
at HTTPParser.parserOnIncomingClient [as onIncoming] (http.js:1628:21)
at HTTPParser.parserOnHeadersComplete [as onHeadersComplete] (http.js:119:23)
at CleartextStream.socketOnData [as ondata] (http.js:1523:20)
at CleartextStream.read [as _read] (tls.js:470:10)
at CleartextStream.Readable.read (_stream_readable.js:294:10)
at EncryptedStream.write [as _write] (tls.js:344:25)
```

I don't understand why I'm stuck with that as I'm following very carefully a lot of tutorials. Even when I clone the authors project I'm still getting this error.

Hope you can help.

UPDATE : I added

```
stream.on('error', function(error, code) {
    console.log("My error: " + error + ": " + code);
});
```

To my stream function and I'm getting a HTTP 401 error

Any ideas ?

Comment: Hi, was it Unauthorized HTTP authentication?
Twitter says 401 is either:
1. a non-existent username or an incorrect password.
2. too many incorrect password guesses or other login rate limiting. What was your problem?

Answer (score 2):

Everything with your code looks fine except for the spelling of "token" in the parameters passed to the constructor for `twitter`. You need to change `access_tocken_key` to `access_token_key` and `access_tocken_secret` to `access_token_secret`. Your error (401) is an authentication issue; that change should hopefully result in ntwitter passing the correct user authentication details to the Twitter API.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and it was because my servers system clock had floated by six minutes. Usually, API's give you about a five minute margin of error.